# MySQL Query students that studied for all the schools

Tags: mysql

Table consists of School_id and Student_name.

```
School_id   Student_Name
1           Raj
1           Tan
1           Brian
2           Raj
2           Brian
3           Raj
3           Tan
```

So the output should be Raj, as Raj has studied in all schools(1,2,3).

Comment: Show what you've tried and where it is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If the total number of different schools is known, then you can use the following query:

```
SELECT Student_Name
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Student_Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT School_id) = 3
```

Otherwise, you can use a subquery in place of `3`, like the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT School_id)
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the number of schools in a subquery using count(distinct ...), join this number to the outer query where you count the number of schools a student is associated with and filter in the having clause.

```
SELECT Student_Name, COUNT(DISTINCT School_id), t1.school_count
FROM yourtable
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT School_id) as school_count FROM yourtable) t1
GROUP BY Student_Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT School_id) = t1.school_count
```

Comment: Think this is bad syntax ... `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT School_id)`

Comment: @dbmitch: no, it is correct syntax, see MySQL documentation on count(distinct ...): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct If this was the reason for a downvote, then pls retract it.

Comment: Will do - tested on Fiddle and it didn't like it - must be website issue?

Comment: Can't possibly tell you what caused an unknown error in an unknown sql statement.

Comment: It's your sql - error is `Unknown column 't1.school_count' in 'having clause'` tested on  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52fb7/10

Comment: No, you used an incorrect underscore character in the having clause, this is why the 2 field names did not match. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52fb7/22

Comment: That's different SQL than what you posted - I just copied/pasted from your answer.

Comment: No, you did not just copy paste. Anyway, just proved that it works.

Comment: Your edit works because you included extra columns. Without the added columns it doesn't. Edit history shows original sql.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT Student_Name
FROM Table 
WHERE 
    COUNT(School_id) = (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM Table 
        GROUP_BY(School_id)
    )
GROUP BY (Student_Name)
```

Comment: You cannot use a group by function in the where clause because its result is not available yet.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

> EDIT: Add description

Simple solution to your exact request

Retrieves only Student Name(s) by checking for all students that have attended all schools (number of distinct schools in list must be equal  to number of distinct schools attended by student)

```
SELECT Student_Name
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Student_Name
HAVING Count(School_ID) =
  (SELECT Count(School_ID) 
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT School_ID FROM Table1) t1
  )
```

Comment: Reason for downvote? "Answer is not useful" is supposed to be the reason. If it works as user requested it is useful. If you don't think it's an ideal solution, it's more appropriate to comment. In either case it's more appropriate to comment

Comment: Wasn't me, but they probably downvoted it because it isn't useful. All you did was post a snippet of code, with absolutely no explanation at all. The purpose of posting an answer is to actually answer the question, not just provide some code that may or may not work in every possible scenario.

Comment: To whomever flagged this as low quality, [you're doing it wrong](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue). Downvote unuseful answers. Don't flag